# Enumerated TabPages in a MenuStrip - Click event

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, tabs

I am displaying all tab pages from a WinForms TabControl into a MenuStrip.

Populating the menu was quite simple however I cant seem to be able to get the event handler to set focus to the TabPage when selected.

As the tabpages are created dynamically they do NOT have a object name. So in the menu_click event the line `tabEditor.SelectedTab = tabpage;` has no meaning.

How can I link the menu_click event to show the selected tab ?

```
    private void pagesToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //first clear all items already loaded
        pagesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear();

        //now re-populate them
        foreach (TabPage t in tabEditor.TabPages)
        {
            //create a menu item
            ToolStripMenuItem menu = new ToolStripMenuItem(t.Text);


            //add an event handler
            menu.Click += new EventHandler(menu_Click);

            pagesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add( menu );
        }
    }



    void menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem menu = (ToolStripMenuItem) sender;

        //Now show the Tab - something like this !
        // 
        tabEditor.SelectedTab = tabpage;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void tabsToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    //create a menu item
    ToolStripMenuItem menu = new ToolStripMenuItem(t.Text);
    //Associate a tab index with a menu item
    menu.Tag = t.TabIndex;
    ...
}

private void menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem menu = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    //Use a tab index associated with a menu item to select a tab
    tabEditor.SelectedIndex = (int)menu.Tag;
}
```